# Uncaught TypeError - when combining and deleting (splicing) duplicates in Object Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object array with each object having many different keys, but the most important are shown below...

```
productArray = [{
  id: 123,
  name 'Sony TV',
  price: 500,
  stock: 123
},
{
  id: 127,
  name 'Sharp TV',
  price: 750,
  stock: 230
},
{
  id: 123,
  name 'Sony TV',
  price: 500,
  stock: 77
}]
```

Obviously this is much large (say 100 products)... now I wish to combine any duplicates I have (for example the product with name 'Sony TV' - so only one record is in my Object Array and the stock levels are combined and I also wish that the highest price is taken. I have written a nested loop that goes through the object array, then in a second array checks if an item has the same ID, if it does I add the stock levels together, take the highest price then remove the duplicate from the nest loop (as an item may appear more than twice, in fact some items may appear 5 or 6 times). There are some other business rules but these aren't important right now. This is my loop code...

```
for (i = 0; i < productArray.length; i++) {

        // check if duplicate... second loop
        for (j = productArray.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {

            if (productArray[i].id === productArray[j].id && productArray[i].id !== undefined) {
                // overwrite, update and combine values... e.g
                console.log('We have a match with ' +  productArray[i].id);
                productArray[i].stock = productArray[i].stock + productArray[j].stock;
                // remove match item from second array
                productArray[j].splice(j, 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I am doing something very wrong as I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. I'm pretty sure this is because my logic is flawed and I am going about this the wrong way. Can someone please suggest a better way of doing this or explain why my logic is producing the error? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It probably has to do with the fact that you are modifying the array while iterating over it.

Comment: I thought by iterating down on the second array would remove this issue

Answer (score 0):

This is because whenever you are removing the element from the array and you are still running  the second for loop and the case where i>length ... try using this...

```
if ( i < productArray.length && productArray[i].id !== undefined && productArray[i].id === productArray[j].id )
```

You are checking if `productArray[i].id !== undefined` only after checking `productArray[i].id === productArray[j].id` and so if `i>arrayLength` `productArray[i].id` will return an error

Comment: I still get the same error? Perhaps there is a better way for me to find duplicates and do the amendments / calculations that that I have originally tried?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call `.splice()` on something that is not an array. It seems you want

```
 productArray.splice(j, 1);
```

instead of

```
 productArray[j].splice(j, 1);
```

---

The other problem is that you are not checking whether the "duplicate" you found is the element itself. So you are basically emptying the whole array, since every element is a duplicate to itself.

I think you can easily fix that be change your inner loop to only iterate to the ith element:

```
for (j = productArray.length - 1; j > i; j--) {
```

However, iterating over the array in "normal" order in the outer loop is still another problem. Just iterate in reverse order in both loops.

Comment: That is a great spot.. however now I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: @Mark so just replace the order in if

Comment: @MarkSandman: Now that might really be related to the mutation of the array inside the loop. *edit:* The problem is that you are removing the item itself even if it is not a duplicate. You could check whether `i !== j`, however, since you are mutating the array, `i` and `j` might get "out of sync". The better solution is probably to generate a new array.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't be easier to use a map to store duplicate items and then create an array from it?

```
var products = [{
    name: 'Sony TV',
    stock: 123
  },
  {
    name: 'Sharp TV',
    stock: 230
  },
  {
    name: 'Sony TV',
    stock: 77
  }];

var productsMap = {};

_.each(products, function (item) {
  if (!productsMap[item.name]) {
    productsMap[item.name] = item;
  } else {
    productsMap[item.name].stock += item.stock;
  }
});

// map to array
var result = _.values(productsMap)
```

without underscore:

```
var productsMap = {};

for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  var item = products[i];
  if (!productsMap[item.name]) {
    productsMap[item.name] = item;
  } else {
    productsMap[item.name].stock += item.stock;
  }
}

var result = [];
for (var name in productsMap) {
  result.push(productsMap[name]);
}
```

Comment: I can't use underscore!

Comment: 'each' is a simple 'for', 'values' is also a simple iteration.

Comment: added version without underscore